# React.js Retrieving data from specific row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i created a table in React.js, also I use Firebase for data storage, 
here is my table code

```
{tableData.map((row, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={row + index}>
            {row.map((cell, index) => {
                return (
                    <td key={"cell_" + index} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.state.userSurname)}>{cell}</td>
                );
            })}
        </tr>
    );
})}
```

and here is my `this.setState`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    db.onceGetUsers().on("child_added", snap =>{
                var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
                var surname = snap.child("name").child("surname").val();
               this.setState({ users: this.state.users.concat([username])});
               this.setState({ userSurname: this.state.userSurname.concat([surname])})
    })
  }
```

Here is my `handleClick` function:

```
  handleClick(event){
    alert(event)
}
```

So.. here is my problem, alert dialog displays every user surname, and what I'm trying to do is to display surname of user that is clicked in table.. how can i do that? :)

Comment: what is in tableData?

Comment: Ofcourse i forgot, in tableData are usernames

Comment: Only usernames, no surnames?

Comment: only usernames, now onClick on username i want to display clicked user surname :)

Comment: maybe instead of having two state variables for username and surname, you can have one state variable consisting of an array of user objects.

Comment: Are the rows in tableData in the same sort order as the array of surnames?

Comment: @BryanMassoth Yes, they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it like this, if you don't want to change your state structure:

```
handleClick(i){
    alert(this.state.userSurname[i])
}

{tableData.map((row, i) => {
    return (
        <tr key={row + i}>
            {row.map((cell, k) => {
                return (
                    <td key={"cell_" + k} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{cell}</td>
                );
            })}
        </tr>
    );
})}
```

Comment: I displays surname only from 1st username in array :)

Comment: Yea because you have another index when you map `row`.

Comment: Change the name of one of the indexes and their usage.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, `child_added`:

> Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

To display surname of only the user that clicked in table, you need to read data once, example:

```
db.onceGetUsers().once('value').then(snap)=> {
var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
var surname = snap.child("name").child("surname").val();
});
```

> `once`
>
> Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: When i try to retrieve data this way, `once('value', snap=>{` whole retrieved data is null :)

Comment: @jj.badweyn `db.onceGetUsers().once('value').then(snap)=> { snap.forEach(childs)=> { var username = childs.child("name").child("name").val();});`